# Custom validators for Django fields will not run

Tags: django, forms, modelform, django-forms

I've setup a Django page with ModelForm (thanks to the comments) but now my `save()` method isn't defined.

My page which loads the `player_add` view gives a `global name 'save' is not defined` when you try to save the form.

Could someone please explain why this method of saving gives an error, because it actually saves to the model and displays the correct data when I got back to my list of players?

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import re

def validate_email(value):
    return True if validators.email_re.match(value) else False

def validate_phone(value):
    value = re.sub(' ', '', value) # get rid of any spaces
    return True if re.match(r'/^(\d){11}', value) else False # don't think this regex actually works


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    telnum = models.CharField('Telephone', max_length = 15, validators = [validate_phone],
                            error_messages = {  'invalid': _('Please enter a valid phone number')})
    dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth')
    email = models.CharField('MyEmail', max_length = 50, validators = [validate_email],
                            error_messages = {  'invalid': _('Please enter a valid email address.'),
                                                'required': _('You need to enter a valid email address.')})

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Players"
        ordering = ['name']

    class Admin:
        pass

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

`forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from packages.models import Player

class PlayerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
```

And my view for adding to the Player model:

```
def player_add(request):
    form = PlayerForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        cmodel = form.save()
        cmodel = save()
        return redirect(players)
    return render_to_response('players/player_add.html',
                            {'player_form': form},
                            context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: When do they run and when do they not run? Remember that validation rules won't run except when using `ModelForm`'s.

Comment: Right, I didn't know they relied on ModelForms. I haven't put those in yet (which means its even more confusing as to how the `telnum` field validated against my rules last night!

Comment: Your phone number validator seems very restrictive. In the U.S. it's usual to include hyphens when writing phone numbers, and in other countries it's common to write + for the international dialling prefix. It would be more user-friendly if you accepted a wider range of phone number formats.

Comment: Yeah its a very basic setup, simply to help me get to grips with custom validation so doesn't have to really do anything.